# xPath equivalent for CSS :nth-of-type(n)

Tags: html, xpath, css-selectors

How to select **first nodes of their type** using xPath?
In CSS I use *a :nth-of-type(1)*. Expected result is *b*, *с* and *first d* nodes (with text = '1')

```
  <a>
        <b>1
            <c>1</c>
        </b>
        <d>1</d>
        <d>2</d>
        <d>3</d>
    </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tricky in pure XPath 1.0.

In XSLT this would normally be part of a grouping algorithm, so in 2.0 you would write

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-by="node-name()">
   .. current-group()[1] ..
```

Or in standalone XPath 2.0 you could do something like

```
//*[not(node-name() = preceding-sibling::*/node-name())]
```

But I can't see a way of doing it in XPath 1.0. It would be interesting to see why it's needed.

Comment: Michael, thanks for great ideas!

So why is it needed:
I want to implement simple package to [convert css to xpath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-cssxpath). Experts in css and xpath are welcomed to reply if any issues will be found in it.

Answer (score 1):

So, the answer.. Implementation in XPath 1.0 is based on awesome answer of [Michael Kay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/415448/michael-kay).

For *:nth-of-type(1)* it looks like:

```
//a//*[name(preceding-sibling::*[1]) != name()]
```

For *:nth-of-type(n)* where n > 1 it looks like:

```
//a//*[name(preceding-sibling::*[n]) != name() and name(preceding-sibling::*[n-1]) = name()]
```

Sure, it is tricky and in most cases can be replaced by more obvious functions.
The goal was to find XPath implementation of CSS pseudo that will do absolutely the same.

Comment: Don't rely on string comparisons of `name()` - the `name()` function is sensitive to namespace prefixes. You need to test `namespace-uri()` and `local-name()` independently.

Comment: @MichaelKay, namespace-uri is not defined either in css locator. If namespace in dom can make Xpath above matching not the same as CSS :nth-of-type, can you kindly give such example.  
  
Regarding to `name()` and `local-name()` [Xpath Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-local-name) says:

_The string returned by the name function will be the same as the string returned by the local-name function except for element nodes and attribute nodes_

Comment: I have no idea how CSS handles namespaces. But in XPath if you want to compare two elements by name, you should compare the namespace URI and local name, and ignore any prefix. Using name() does not ignore the prefix. (Yes, name() and local-name() are the same except for elements and attributes. But presumably we're mainly concerned with elements!)